# Tensorflow: classifier.predict and predicted_classes

Tags: tensorflow, classification

#### System information

- custom code: no, it is the one in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator
- system: Apple
- OS: Mac OsX 10.13
- TensorFlow version: 1.3.0
- Python version: 3.6.3
- GPU model: AMD FirePro D700 (actually, two such GPUs)

#### Describe the problem

Dear all,
I am running the simple iris program:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator
under python 3.6.3 and tensorflow 1.3.0.
The program executes correctly, apart from the very last part, i.e. the one related to the confusion matrix.
In fact, the result I get for the confusion matrix is:
New Samples, Class Predictions:    [array([b'1'], dtype=object), array([b'2'], dtype=object)]
rather than the expected output:
New Samples, Class Predictions:    [1 2]
Has anything about confusion matrix changed in the latest release?
If so, how should I modify that part of the code?
Thank you very much for your help!
Best regards
Ivan

#### Source code / logs

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a numpy issue. `array([b'1'], dtype=object)` is one way numpy represents the string `'1'`.